# Partial View Form will not submit using Bootstrap Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, bootstrap-modal, client-side-validation

Here is the button to open the modal box (which works):

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-addItem-@sectionCount-@rowCount" class="btn btn-success">Add New List Item</button>
```

Here is the modal:

```
<div id="modal-addItem-@sectionCount-@rowCount" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-addItem-@sectionCount-@rowCount" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Added List Item</h4>
            </div>
            @Html.Partial("_SelectItemType", new ListItemsViewModel { listID = theLists.listID })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is that partial view **Updated**:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectItemType", "ListItems", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.listID)

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <b class="control-label col-md-4">Select List Item Type:</b>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemTypes.itemTypeName, DropDown.GeneralListCreator(get.getItemTypes(true), get.getItemTypes(false))) //This gets a list of item types
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Next Step &raquo;" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}
```

So when I click on the button, it opens up the modal as it should. When I click on the "Next Step >>" button which is the submit button on the form. **No post back, no form submit...nothing happens.**

I'm not sure why this wont work...can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE:** I tried removing the Section script (because it's already in the view), as Chris pointed out but it is still not submitting.

Comment: There's nothing in your code here that would prevent this from working. Although, FWIW, you can't implement a section inside a partial view. That shouldn't cause any problems, though; it just won't include your validation scripts.

Comment: Do you have client-side validation enabled? May be it doesn't prevent the form submission?

Comment: Good clue, I added this below the drop down list in my partial view `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemTypes.itemTypeName)` and received this message: **The Item Type Name must be at least 2 characters long and no longer than 250 characters.** which is the validation message. I will try and troubleshoot a little more from here. Good pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was simple, of course. I found this page: [ASP .NET MVC Disable Client Side Validation at Per-Field Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630424/asp-net-mvc-disable-client-side-validation-at-per-field-level)

It lead me right to the answer that **Vsevolod** kindly pointed out. Validation being enabled on the client side. I wasn't outputting a message before so I didn't know. When I added:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemTypes.itemTypeName)
```

to the form I was able to see the message:

```
The Item Type Name must be at least 2 characters long and no longer than 250 characters.
```

My drop down list was being populated by this method: `get.getItemTypes(false)` which returned **Names** if true and **Numbers(ids)** if false. The id's were 1-9 and were only a SINGLE digit. I required 2 characters to validate. Therefore it was not submitting.

My solution as proposed by the link at the top:

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemTypes.itemTypeName, DropDown.GeneralListCreator(get.getItemTypes(true), get.getItemTypes(true)))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemTypes.itemTypeName)
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
```

For some reason, even once I changed the method `get.getItemTypes(false)` to return the names (send in true), the validation was still not working properly so I had to turn it off and back on.

Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score -1):

This is what helped me:

Try adding

```html
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-addItem-@sectionCount-@rowCount"
```

to your submit. That should close it and allow your data to submit.

Look at this `.modal('toggle')` in [bootstraps documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).