# Is there a data annotation to disable the client validation for just a property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model, which has a field that I don't want it to be validated on client side. Is there a way to turn off the client validation just on the referred field?

Comment: Create and use a view model **specific to the view** !

Comment: Using a view model I think it is redundant for the situation I have. But thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @viniciusalvess, Using a view model is NEVER redundant and is ALWAYS the recommend approach

Comment: Its best you use a view model and don't add the '[Required]' attribute.

Comment: I agrree with you @StephenMuecke , but I'm creating something simple, and the code repeating at the view model kind of bothers me. But thanks to you all that contributed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BatchId, new { @class = "k-textbox" })
    @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
</div>
```

Answer is from here: [ASP .NET MVC Disable Client Side Validation at Per-Field Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630424/asp-net-mvc-disable-client-side-validation-at-per-field-level)

Comment: Thank you @Bruno Garcia that helps a lot. I found out setting the data-val atribute to false works too. But I think your aproach is more clear ! Example I found out : Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.banco.nome, new { class = "form-control", id = "pessoa_banco", placeholder = "Pesquisar...", data_val = false })