# asp.net mvc 5, validation for not required fields(optional fields)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i've a form that some of the fields is not required to be filled or optional fields in asp.net mvc 5 application.

i've tried this things but, warning message for "this fields is required", keep showing.

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
public string country { get; set; }

adding htmlAttribute
@required = false
```

Data Model

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    ...

    public string country { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class CountryLists
{
    ...
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "SignUp", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "signUpForms", id = "signUpForm", @class = "registerLogin-form" }))
{
...
    if (Model.MembershipProgram.StsSignUpCountry)
    {
        <div class="form-group col-12">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.country, 
          new SelectList(Model.CountryLists, "CountryCode", "CountryName"),
          "Select Country",
            new
            {
                id = "select_country",
                @class = "form-control"
            })
        </div>
    }
...
<button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary pull-right active" name="command" value="Save">
            @ViewBag.JoinNow <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
</button>
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove that `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]`

Comment: yes i was removed that, but the warning keep showing :\.
before i dont use that

Comment: can you post the html which is rendered in your browser?

Comment: <div class="form-group col-12">
 <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The country field is required." id="select_country" name="country">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="CO0169">Yemen</option>
  <option value="CO0170">Zambia</option>
  <option value="CO0171">Zimbabwe</option>
  ...
 </select>
</div>

Comment: I think the problem is some how it is adding `data-val="true"` which is causing this issue. You need to check some where in your model from which you are binding it is written.

Comment: are you using the same name "country" in your code some where can you show more code like which model you are using on your cshtml file.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `value= false` in `web.config` for `ClientValidationEnabled`

```
<appSettings><add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" /></appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

might be duplicat of : [ASP .NET MVC Disable Client Side Validation at Per-Field Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630424/asp-net-mvc-disable-client-side-validation-at-per-field-level)

may be it helps: If your are using MVC4 and latest version you can write it as

```
 @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }
 if (Model.MembershipProgram.StsSignUpCountry)
 {
    <div class="form-group col-12">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.country, 
      new SelectList(Model.CountryLists, "CountryCode", "CountryName"),
      "Select Country",
        new
        {
            id = "select_country",
            @class = "form-control"
        })
    </div>
}
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
```

Comment: ddn't work :'
the message still showing, that make me cant submit the form

Comment: did you write @Html.ValidationMessage for country? or it is giving  system generated message. if you have written it you should remove that.

Comment: try this @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.country, 
      new SelectList(Model.CountryLists, "CountryCode", "CountryName"),
      "Select Country",
        new
        {
            id = "select_country",  data_val = "false",
            @class = "form-control"
        })

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be `CountryCode`.
Check your model if it is an integer then it should be like

```
 public int? CountryCode{ get; set; }
```

You will have a model with two properties at least

```
  public int CountryCode{ get; set; }
  public string CountryName{ get; set; }
```

You have mentioned in your code as below

```
new SelectList(Model.CountryLists, "CountryCode", "CountryName"),
```

Comment: this is my CountryLists Data Model
public class HEM002
    {
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryAcr { get; set; }
    }